# vshost32.exe failing due to poor naming class and object managment

Tags: c#

I am not a seasoned pro at C# and am running into an error I cannot find a discrete solution to. Currently I have one class that is part of my namespace

```
namespace BlackBoxStudio
{
    public partial class Project : Form
    {
```

This Project class is what implements the various functions of my form. What I am trying to do is make a `label.text` field  accessable to another .cs class within the same namespace. As so, I have made the corresponding fields public:

```
 public string lb_InformationText
    {
        get { return lb_Information.Text; }
        set { lb_Information.Text = value; }
    }
```

To call these I get or set methods in my `RsaFunctions` class I make a new private `project` as so:

```
namespace BlackBoxStudio
{
    class RsaFunctions 
    {
        //private Project proj =  new Project();
```

However the line that is commented our causes my vshost32.exe application to fail and the program dies. Why is this causing the vshost32.exe to fail when I un-comment the corresponding line? Or how could I better structure my classes so this does not happen? Any tips would be much appreciated about my strategy for making new classes and such.

Comment: If the Project form is already running you don't want to create a new instance of it (which is what you're doing). You need to pass the already created instance to RsaFunctions, as a parameter in the RsaFunctions constructor method, for example.

Comment: I get what your saying but i am struggling with the syntax Michael. I have tried variations of that but the host.exe still crashes.                class RsaFunctions  
        {
            private Project proj;

            public RsaFunctions(Project proj)
            {
                this.proj = proj;
            }

Comment: So it still crashes without instantiating a new instance of Project? There must be something else in the RsaFunctions class that is conflicting with the Project class (I can only guess without seeing the code). There also might be some component on your form that is somehow in conflict with vshost32. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think I found a solution, it seems to be working                         `using (Project derp = new Project())
                        {
                            derp.lb_InformationText = "this is a test";
                        }`